# addView does not working (Linear Layout)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

This is my first question. I want to add a textview to an existing layout every second using the addView method. And I want to print the text down while they remain. But nothing appear in the layout. Hope somebody can help me.
This is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = this.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    textView = this.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    linearLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.line1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            runThread();
        }
    });

}

private void runThread(){

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(i++ < 10) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView createdTextView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                        createdTextView.setText(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString() + i);
                        linearLayout.addView(createdTextView);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

This is avtivity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/line1"
    tools:context="com.example.runonuithread.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post code here .

Comment: Add your `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: _Added things._

Comment: try to remove `this` from `linearLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.line1);` as no need to give reference of class while getting view from xml

Comment: you haven't given any params for the textView or any text ... try giving params to it and set some text in it

Comment: Tnx  Ahsu! But still dosen't work.
Where should the param be given?

Comment: set width and height in textview

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView createdTextView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
createdTextView.setText(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString() + i);
createdTextView.setLayoutParams(lparams);    
linearLayout.addView(createdTextView);
```

Comment: Tnx your answer! I can't find LayoutParams so tried this.

Comment: LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams lparams  = new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);